# Is it possible to cross-compile adb for old c89 compiler arm-linux-gcc --version 2.95.2?

Tags: gcc, adb, cross-compiling, c89

I want to compile adb with an old arm compiler:

arm-linux-gcc --version
2.95.2

But adb sources seem to be c99 and it seems this compiler only wants c89.
Would it be impossible to compile adb somehow anyway? Compiling an old version of adb
or moving declarations first in c source files.

Any ideas welcome!

Comment: Can you add the compiler flag `-std=c99`?

Comment: Why do you need to use a 15 year old compiler?

Comment: No it doesn't seem to work. I need to run adb on 10 year old hardware.